# How to know my base station?

Tags: mobile-network

I am an android user and I would like to know what are the available base stations and what is the base station that I'm getting signals from. How can I know that? Is there a way?
Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to get the cell tower id and location using the [`PhoneStateListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION) of the Android API.

Here are some apps that seems to use this feature to show some information about the nearest cell towers :

- [OpenSignal - 3G/4G/WiFi maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.staircase3.opensignal&hl=en)
- [Signal Finder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.akvelon.signaltracker&hl=en)
- [Antennas](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.technolatry.antennas&feature=search_result)

Comment: Also, Llama, the automation tool, works on Cell Tower signature - it has a listing of when they are in range to trigger actions.

Comment: I've used OpenSignal in the past when I was troubleshooting 3G connection issues, it does this sort of thing well.